# How do I explicitly disable chunked streaming mode for HTTP connections in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-networking

I'm targeting a REST web service from Android 4.0 using `HttpsURLConnection`. This works fine unless I try to `POST` something. This is the relevant code section:

```
   connection.setDoOutput(true);
   connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

   ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   serializeObjectToStream(out, object);
   byte[] array = out.toByteArray();
   connection.getOutputStream().write(array, 0, array.length);
```

This throws the following exception:

```
   java.net.HttpRetryException: Cannot retry streamed HTTP body
```

From debugging I realized that the output stream I get via `connection.getOuputStream()` is of type `ChunkedOutputStream` and from digging in Androids source code I figured that if a request needs to be retried (for whatever reason), it pokes with the above exception, because it figures out that it is *not* using a `RetryableOutputStream` that it wants there.

The question is now: How do I make my HttpsURLConnection return such a RetryableOutputStream, or rather, how can I prevent chunked request encoding properly? I *thought* I did that already with `setChunkedStreamingMode(0)`, but apparently this is not the case...

**[edit]**

No, the implementation of `java.net.HTTPUrlConnection` ignores a streaming mode of 0 or lower:

```
 public void setChunkedStreamingMode(int chunkLength) {
    [...]
    if (chunkLength <= 0) {
        this.chunkLength = HttpEngine.DEFAULT_CHUNK_LENGTH;
    } else {
        this.chunkLength = chunkLength;
    }
}
```

Comment: On a related note: I think the reason _why_ it wants a RetryableOutputStream at all is because there is a Basic Auth protection configured on the REST server and Android's HttpURLConnectionImpl seems to automatically retry a request when it gets an 401 Unauthorized answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bummer! The solution is to not call `setChunkedStreamingMode()` (or even `setFixedStreamingMode()`) from the client code at all! "-1" are the internal default values for fixedLength and chunkedLength and cannot be set client-side, because setting a value lower or equal to "0" lets it default to `HttpEngine.DEFAULT_CHUNK_LENGTH` (or throws an exception in the fixed streaming mode case).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to set a `Content-Length` header (which may be set by this next part) and call `setFixedLengthStreamingMode` with the proper length of the POST message you intend to send.

See the "streaming mode" section in this SO FAQ:

[Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Comment: You should never set the `Content-length` header in Java. `setFixedLengthStreamingMode()` will do that anyway, and override whatever is already set. NB If you call `setChunkedStreamingMode()` there *is* no `Content-length` header, and you should definitely not set one. And if you don't call either of these methods, `HttpURLConnection` will set it to the correct value all by itself.

Comment: @EJP Perhaps my comment was unclear, but I tried to imply that `setFixedLengthStreamingMode` would set the header for you. The original question is clearly requesting a non-chunked request so that it may be "retried". The original poster also replied *6 years ago* saying that any call to `set*StreamingMode` would break this. So, manually-setting the `Content-Length` does make some sense under certain conditions.